# Length of unsigned char *?

Tags: c, algorithm

```
void HorspoolMatching(unsigned char T[], char P[])
{

    int i = 0, k, m, n;
    int count = 0;
    //int *p;
    int val;

    ShiftTable(P);

    m = strlen(P);
    n = strlen(T);

    i = m - 1;

    while(i < n)
    {
        k = 0;

        while((k < m ) && (P[m - 1 - k] == T[i - k]))
        {
            k++;
        }

        if(k == m)
        {
            count++;
            i += m;


        } else{
            val = (int)T[i];
            if (val < 0 || val >= MAX) {
                i = i + m;
            } else {
                i = i + table[val];
            }

        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", count);
}
```

...

```
printf("Enter name of the data file: ");
                scanf("%s", filenameFOUR);

                FILE *fp4;

                fp4 = fopen(filenameFOUR, "r");

                if(fp4 == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Error");
                    exit(0);
                }

                while((inc = fgetc(fp4)) != EOF)
                {
                    buf[n++] = (char) inc;

                }

                fclose(fp4);

                 printf("Enter a pattern to search: ");
                 scanf("%s", pat2);


                 ftime(&before);
                 HorspoolMatching(buf, pat2);
                 ftime(&after);

                 int diffTime4 = (after.time - before.time)*1000 +
                    (after.millitm - before.millitm);

                printf("Time it took: %d milliseconds.\n", diffTime4);
```

How do I get the length of the unsigned parameter without an error? I was advised to change to unsigned chars because my output is incorrect. Im trying to go through a test file to find matches using the horspool algorithm.

```
warning: passing 'unsigned char *' to parameter of type
      'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different
      sign [-Wpointer-sign]
        n = strlen(T);
                   ^
/usr/include/string.h:82:28: note: passing argument to parameter here
size_t   strlen(const char *);
```

Comment: Add your main..

Comment: What is `table`? What is `ShiftTable`? Please read this [mcve].

Comment: If you have a *string* why do you use `unsigned char` instead of just `char`? If the data is *not* a string, then you can't use `strlen` and must pass the length of the data as an argument to your function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the reason to use unsigned char is the horspool string search algorithm...

Comment: If it is non-text data, which can contain zeroes, then it's not a string and you can't use string functions like `strlen`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude A _string_ is a sequences of characters ending with a null character - not necessarily of type `char`.  What problem do you see with using `unsigned char *` instead of `char *`, especially since the string functions treat all the elements as if they were `unsigned char`?

Answer (score 3):

You could cast the `unsigned char *` to `char *` for `strlen` without ill effects. However, there is a far more pressing issue with your code.

Since the `char`s might be signed, `P[m - 1 - k] == T[i - k]` is incorrect: then `P[m]` would be signed and `T[n]` would be unsigned - the characters that have sign bit on wouldn't match (i.e. having unsigned value >= 128 on machine with `CHAR_BIT` 8). As the [Horspool's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm) uses the characters as index to arrays, it would be easiest to have both parameters as `unsigned char[]`. Even better: use a variable of type `unsigned char *` to represent them, while accepting `char *` as the argument:

```
void HorspoolMatching(char T[], char P[]) {
    unsigned char *t = (unsigned char*)T;
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*)P;
    // and use t and p here on.
}
```

---

However, it is more common to write the matching so that it also accepts the length of the strings as parameters - often the length of the string is known beforehand so calculating it again within the function would be costly. Thus I'd recommend declaring the function as

```
char *HorspoolMatching(char T[], size_t T_len, char P[], size_t P_len);
```

`void` as the return value isn't useful either - I'd `char *` to the beginning of first match, or NULL if no match is found.